# SSH Passphrase for ppk file

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect to EC2 server, using .ppk file

```
ssh -i key.ppk -l root@dns-name
```

The issue is that, the shell asks for passphrase ? i don't know what is it!
Am able to use this key using putty, but not from linux

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Where did you get this key from? Can you go back to the source and ask for the passphrase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ppk format keys are for putty only.

For OpenSSH you need to use OpenSSH format keys.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74545/what-difference-between-openssh-key-and-putty-key

Comment: Thanks, you are right i had to change the ppk to openssh format